# Trigonometry problem 1

Tags: trigonometry

> In $\triangle ABC$ if $\angle C=60^{\circ}$ then show that
>   $$\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}=\frac{3}{a+b+c}.$$

I try to solve this problem but not getting the proof. How to solve this problem ?
Please try to help me or give me hint

Comment: Is $a$ the side of the triangle opposite the angle $A$? (and same for $b$ and $c$)?

Comment: If the angle at $C$ is $\pi/3$, the cosine rule gives $c^2=a^2+b^2-ab$. You should be able to rearrange this into your equation.

Comment: To echo @Dibbs comment a picture to clarify what A, B, C and a, b, c are would help. I'm assuming A, B and C are angles, a, b and c are sides. a is opposite A, b is opposite B and c is opposite C.  This detail needs to be in your  question and could either be in words as I have done in this comment or a picture.

Answer (score 3):

By clearing the denominators in your equation, we obtain the equivalent one
$$(a+b+c)(a+b+2c)=3(a+c)(b+c),$$
that is
$$a^2+ab+2ca+ab+b^2+2bc+ca+bc+2c^2=3ab+3ca+3bc+3c^2$$
or
$$a^2+b^2=ab+c^2$$
which holds by the [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab(1/2)=a^2+b^2-ab.$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that
$$(a+b+c)(a+b+2c)=3(c+a)(c+b)$$ or
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-ab$$ and since by law of cosines $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\measuredangle C$, we obtain
$$\cos\measuredangle C=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear[image]

I try as above . Shall I tak left hand side first ?